# I can't value fields iText 2.1.7

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

We have created PDF files via a template and we fill the fields with values from the database. `"Name field" = "value".`
Now we want to read the value of one of the fields in the PDF file we created earlier.

**CODE**

```
reader = new PdfReader("C:\\temp\\letter.pdf");

baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);

form = stamper.getAcroFields();

System.out.println(form.getField("CUSTOMER-NAME"));
```

But when I do that returns "null" and it does not recognize any field. It is as if the fields does not exist.

Any help would appreciated. Thanks.

Hi,
I have 2 file types. One has been flattened :-( and another one no.
For the last file, i am using this code and it work:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(FILE);
PdfDictionary root = reader.getCatalog();
PdfDictionary form1 = root.getAsDict(PdfName.ACROFORM);
PdfArray fields = form1.getAsArray(PdfName.FIELDS);

PdfDictionary page;
PdfArray annots;
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
    page = reader.getPageN(i);
    annots = page.getAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
    for (int j = 0; j < annots.size(); j++) {
        fields.add(annots.getAsIndirectObject(j));
    }
}

AcroFields form2 = reader.getAcroFields();
```

Thanks a lot!!!
Regards,
Muni

Comment: There has never been an iText version 2.7.1. Assuming that you are using iText 2.1.7, you should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696851/can-itext-2-1-7-or-earlier-can-be-used-commercially If you ever want an answer to your question, you'll have to supply `letter.pdf` for inspection. Finally: if reading the field values is all you want to do: why on earth are you creating a `PdfStamper` instance?

Comment: *It is as if the fields does not exist* - did you probably flatten the firm?

Comment: Thanks Pankajparkar. Im sorry for my mistake... How I could attach the PDF file?

Answer (score 0):

As bruno suggested - if you only want to read, only use the PdfReader...

Try the following code and see whether something is printed out:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C:\\temp\\letter.pdf");
AcroFields acroFields = reader.getAcroFields();
Map<String, AcroFields.Item> fields = acroFields.getFields();
Iterator<Entry<String, Item>> it = fields.entrySet().iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    Entry<String, Item> entry = it.next();
    String value = acroFields.getField(entry.getKey());
    System.out.println(entry.getKey()+":"+value);
}
```

There could be many reasons why your field is not found:

- the PDF doesn't contain PDF form fields at all (pdf has been flattened)
- the field name is a different one (e.g. Customer-Name)
- you field has a parent (so the name is parent.CUSTOMER-NAME)
- the form fields were not correctly inserted
- ...

Can you see the fields in e.g. adobe reader?